# Get index value of an array by it's value in PHP from JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this array structure i want to get the hour which have 14 value after finding that i need to get the index of that array which i need to filter other element please help.

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/aa433737d95d5869/hourly/q/US/Los%20Angeles%20International.json");
$json = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($json as  $value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);
    echo "</pre>";
    print_r(search($value, 'hour', '14'));
    echo find_parent($value, '14');    
}
```

Comment: please show us your string content.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Just vist the [url](http://api.wunderground.com/api/aa433737d95d5869/hourly/q/US/Los%20Angeles%20International.json)

Comment: So you want only the array, what has value of 14 or the index of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($json['hourly_forecast'] as $key => $val) {
    if ($val['FCTTIME']['hour'] == 14) {
        die('The key is where hour is 14 is: ' . $key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach like this to get each key => value pair and do whatever you want:

```
<?php
foreach ($json  as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === "hour") {
        if ($value === "14") {
            // do whatever
        }
    }    
}
?>
```

From the api you showed, it looks like you'd have to dig a bit deeper into the array though, but this is how you'd achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you would like to pick out the `FCTTIME` item where `hour` is equal to 14 you could do like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/aa433737d95d5869/hourly/q/US/Los%20Angeles%20International.json");

// decode the json string 
$object = json_decode($json);

// loop through each `hourly_forecast` item and check if `FCTTIME->hour` is equal to 14
foreach ($object->hourly_forecast as $index => $forecast) {
  if($forecast->FCTTIME->hour == 14) {
     // the $index contains the items position in the `hourly_forecast` array
  }
}
```